# Sharing Config Files Across Apps - Android 10 and Beyond

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, android-10.0, android-storage

My company has three different Android apps that provide functionality for sales reps. We opted to separate the apps into "modules" because not all reps need all the modules. Up to now we have been using a JSON file in a directory on the SD card of the devices to set some configuration data for the apps. However, it appears that with Android 10 and beyond this will no longer be possible.

Currently we use getExternalStorageDirectory() to access the SDCARD and then open a file inside a directory our app creates.

Since we want the file access to not be something the sales reps have any control over we want it to happen transparently. However it does not seem this will be possible going forward.

Will using a custom FileProvider or even a DocumentsProvider be a way to continue to share data between our apps?

Another question, although not as important, is, can we change the default location of the DB files our app creates as we do now in earlier versions of Android?

Thanks

Rich

Comment: "then open a file inside a directory our app creates" -- earlier, though, you indicated that you had three apps, not one. Which app is creating the file? Or, where is the file coming from originally?

Comment: Hi - The config file and the app(s) are put on the devices before the tablets are deployed to the reps but then the file may be updated via MDM. Additionally the developers (like myself) and QA team will modify the config files to test the app against our QA environment as well so none of the apps create the file, they all just read it.

Comment: You might ask your MDM supplier if they have any suggestions, as not only are you limited by Android 10 but by how the MDM system works. In general, Android is a consumer operating system, and so Google wants to put control in the hands of the user. This runs counter to your objective ("we want the file access to not be something the sales reps have any control over").

Comment: Thanks. I will see if the MDM vendor has any thoughts.